# Why am I getting two different hashCodes?

Tags: c#

This is my code. Why is the hashcode of my two objects not the same?

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Person p1 = new Person()
    {
        Age = 21,
        Name = "Anna"
    };

    Person p2 = new Person()
    {
        Age = 21,
        Name = "Anna"
    };

    int i = p1.GetHashCode();
    int j = p2.GetHashCode();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Show us the hashcode and provide more info

Comment: just copy paste the code and see that there are two different values on i and j

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're not overriding `GetHashCode`, you'll be using the [System.Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx) version by inheritance.

> The GetHashCode method can be overridden by a derived type. If GetHashCode is not overridden, hash codes for reference types are computed by calling the Object.GetHashCode method of the base class, **which computes a hash code based on an object's reference**

In other words, since they're not the same *object instance*, they won't have the same hash code.

To make them have the same hash code, you'll have to implement your own GetHashCode by overriding it in the Person class, for example the simple;

```
public override int GetHashCode ()
{
    return Name.GetHashCode () ^ Age.GetHashCode ();
}
```

Comment: ok, so how can i make those two "same data object" to hold the same hashcode without override ?

Comment: Try making them structs, or override their `GetHashCode` methods.

Comment: @Yanshof You should probably read the docs around hash codes.

Answer (score 2):

Because they are not the same object, just holding the same data.